# Why button controls are not having Dependancy properties for Name, Height e.t.c. & User control need all DP to grab the values in WPF-MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf

I was learning about the delegates & DP, and I realized that the UserControl in WPF needs to have a DP to bind the assigned value of its property to user control in xaml.

Xaml e.g. `<local:MyControl MyTitle="xyz" />`  which having

```cs
public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "MyTitle",
    typeof(string),
    typeof(MyControl),
    new PropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(MySomeMethod))
);
```

- `MySomeMethod` is anything where I do further stuff with property value.
- New `PropertyChangedCallback(OnSetTextChanged)` is the delegate responsible for getting the callbacks from the Parent control(where the user control is placed) to my actual user control.

So my question is **`Button` control is also one control**, and I check its properties like name, etc, so there are normal CLR properties only and **no DP and not having a such mechanism for callbacks like DP** then **how does the value actually travel from our page to the actual button class??**.

```
<Button Name="blaa" Height="10"/>
```

like in the case of user control we need DP with delegates for callbacks then why does Button not need these things?

I checked the button class it doesn't have DP defined for `Name`, it is normal CLR property !! Maybe it's a silly but deep question, but it grabs my curiosity..please correct me on this!!

Comment: The `Name=""` in `<Button Name="">` has its `DependencyProperty` at `FrameworkElement.NameProperty`.

Comment: Be aware that `Name` is actually a dependency property. All dependency properties come with a "CLR wrapper", that is a property definition with a getter that calls GetValue and setter that calls SetValue for the associated dependency property identifier field. Click however is not a property, but an event.

Comment: See [Custom dependency properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/properties/custom-dependency-properties?view=netdesktop-6.0) for how to properly declare a dependency property.

Comment: Also be aware that for `MyControl MyTitle="xyz"`, the property `MyTitle` does not necessarily have to be a dependency property. You can also set a standard CLR property in XAML. You can however not apply a Binding, Style Setter, animation etc.